# elasticsearch query to return mongodb documents less than _id

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to return all documents whose _id is less than a given _id but am failing to retrieve so. Query that I am trying is:

```
 curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/smartjn/feed_details/_search" -d' {"query":{"range":{"uid":{"gte":"56f43c0344fc86e73b1170b0"}}}}'
This gives me result as: 
{"took":21,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

However, I can see 10K records which have _id > what I metioned above. Any idea how do I accomplish this.

In MongoDB I use

```
 '_id' => [
'$lt' =>
new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($_GET['lastid'])
]
```

To achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

When I execute a test, I am getting successful results. Can you post your index mapping for the field uid? `localhost:9200/smartjn/_mapping/feed_details/field/uid`

```
  pancake$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/test_index/test_type2/_search -d '{"query":{"range":{"uid":{"gte":"56f43c0344fc86e73b1170b0"}}}}'

 {"took":11,"timed_out":false,"_shards":
 {"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":
 {"total":4,"max_score":1.0,"hits": [
    {"_index":"test_index","_type":"test_type2","_id":"AVeLab8ILs6L_WBjvpfv","_score":1.0,"_source":{"uid":"56f43c0344fc86e73b1170b0"}},
    {"_index":"test_index","_type":"test_type2","_id":"AVeLadPoLs6L_WBjvpfx","_score":1.0,"_source":{"uid":"56f43c0344fc86e73b1170b2"}},
    {"_index":"test_index","_type":"test_type2","_id":"AVeLadp4Ls6L_WBjvpfy","_score":1.0,"_source":{"uid":"56f43c0344fc86e73b1170b3"}},
    {"_index":"test_index","_type":"test_type2","_id":"AVeLacwhLs6L_WBjvpfw","_score":1.0,"_source":{"uid":"56f43c0344fc86e73b1170b1"}}
 ]}}
```

Quick question, you asked "I am looking for a way to return all documents whose _id is **less than** a given _id but am failing to retrieve so." and then you're using a **gte** (greater than or equal) query. What result are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot Pancake, that was a typo from my end. I should have typed _uid whereas I typed uid . Regards